# Raster data, basics: where is the information?

Tags: qgis, raster, dimensions

A long time ago I worked a bit with ArcGIS and shapefiles but never with raster data. Now, I have a raster dataset that I use in QGIS. Ok, no biggy I thought. Just convert it to shape/ vector and all we be well. But it's not. The data is supposed to show 26 time steps, yet all I get after conversion is a single number per cell. According to the description, the "data are provided in NetCDF-4 format, where the third dimension represents the time step". What is this third dimension?

This is the dataset I am talking about: https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.dk1j0

I am trying to access the GDP pc 5 arc minutes dataset. How can I transform this into a shapefile in such a way that I get access to the 26 time steps?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! What is your ultimate goal with the data? It might be possible that converting it to a shapefile is not the best idea, especially because of its three dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the warm welcome! My goal is to merge the dataset with another - a spatial merge - and afterwards exporting the results as a csv for statistical analysis. I have done that before for shapefiles, but rasters give me a headache.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install [Crayfish](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/crayfish/) plugin, which will add some Mesh algorithms in the QGIS Processing Toolbox.

(1) Load the NetCDF file as a mesh layer, by `Menu > Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer` and select your NetCDF file (.nc).

(2) Please follow steps in a picture below:

[image]

1. Prepare a point shapefile at your intended research location.
2. Activate **Export 2D timeseries plot data** in the `Processing Toolbox > Crayfish`
3. In the new dialog box, (3) select the input mesh layer (.nc)
4. `Points for data export` should be your point of interest (see 1. above).
5. Click on <kbd>...</kbd> at the right-hand side of `Exported data CSV file` and select `Save to file` (so you won't have to wonder where the output has gone...)

(3) Once completed, you will have a csv file like below:

[image]

`time` column (1990, 1991,...) is the timestep field, where you will find 26 rows.
You may or may not want to join this csv with your point shapefile afterwords.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response! One question: I saw a video in which the person right clicked the raster in the layer section -> properties -> single pseudo colour. The suggestion was to select eacht time step manually and make a shapefile out of it. Sure it's tedious, but is that a viable work around?

Comment: By saying "shapefile", do you mean to get all measured points over the map extent?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite catch your question. I mean a shapefile or vector layer that covers the entire map for one time step, another shapefile (vector layer) for the second time step, and so on and so on. In the end I would merge all shapefiles and get a dataset that tells me 26 time steps for each cell.

Comment: @Hamster Then you can use `Export mesh vertices` tool in the Crayfish plugin.